# Powershell Script is getting executed remotely through C# client but not from Powershell window

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to run the following script CreateUser.ps1:

```
$comp = [ADSI]('WinNT://MachineName,computer');
$user = $comp.Create('User', 'User121');
$user.SetPassword('Welcome1$');
$user.SetInfo();
$user.Description = "Created through powershell client";
$user.SetInfo();
```

I am running the script in a remote machine from the powershell window with the following step:

```
 $cred = Get-Credential

 $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName MachineName -ConfigurationName Microsoft.PowerShell -Credential $cred

Import-PSSession $session
```

Running the script with the following command :

```
C:\scripts\CreateUser.ps1
```

I am getting the following exception :

```
Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied.
"
At C:\scripts\createUser.ps1:4 char:14
+ $user.SetInfo <<<< ();
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI

Cannot set the Value property for PSMemberInfo object of type "System.Management.Automation.PSMethod".
At C:\scripts\createUser.ps1:5 char:7
+ $user. <<<< Description = "Created through powershell client";
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied.
"
At C:\scripts\createUser.ps1:6 char:14
+ $user.SetInfo <<<< ();
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI
```

But doing the same from C# client works fine

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, "MachineName", 5985, "/wsman", shellUri, credential);
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
   {
                runspace.Open();
                using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                    String file = @"C:\scripts\createUser.ps1";
                    powershell.Commands.AddScript(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file));
                    Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
                  }
      }
```

Comment: i guess you have not launch an elevated powershell console.

Comment: Another script which gets all the users is working fine.

Comment: you're not getting something here, you are setting ! ^^

Comment: Yes.I am getting the error while setting. I tried running the powershell command prompt as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression that you are thinking that you are running the command against computer A while your are running it on your computer. Import-PSSession allows you to use commands, modules from another computer on your computer.

You might want to look into invoke-command -Session $session -scriptBlock { Put your code here}

Comment: Or, in this case, use `Invoke-Command -Session $session -FilePath C:\scripts\CreateUser.ps1`

Comment: For invoke-Command, are we creating a custom runspace like we create using WSManagement?

Comment: You probably know more than I do about custom runspaces. Invoke-Command is using WSManagement but you don't need to do anything special as long as PowerShell remoting is enabled on the remote computer (you can use test-wsman to check).  Here is more info on Invoke-Command. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx It "is" the way you would mostly use to fan out and run stuff on multiple computers

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved when I tried from a fresh powershell Windows.